# Typescript 0.9.5 extend array prototype with move function

Tags: typescript

I need to extend native array with new prototype function move which basicly sorts items in the array. But I got error on compile `

```
Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
    while (old_index < 0) {
         old_index += this.length;
    }
    while (new_index < 0) {
        new_index += this.length;
    }
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            this.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    //return this; // for testing purposes
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you are getting is probably:

> The property 'move' does not exist on value of type 'any[]'.

To fix this, you need to define the method on the Array interface, in addition to your code. For example:

```
interface Array {
    move(old_index: number, new_index: number): void;
}
```

**Note:** In TypeScript 1.0 you must write `interface Array<T>`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I get the error you just wrote. Unfortunatly I tried to use interface Array {
    move(old_index: number, new_index: number): void;
} but I still have the same issue.

Comment: On my computer typescript 0.9.5. And I still have this error. I have resharper 8.1 and web essensials installed.

Comment: @Roman that's very strange. Make sure the interface is either referenced in the file you're using `move` or just try having the interface directly in the file you're using `move`.